Sampling Gauss-Bernoulli RBM
In the 2018 paper Stein Variational Gradient Descent Without Gradient the authors analyze the sampling performance of their algorithm on multiple benchmarks. One of them is sampling from a Gauss-Bernoulli Restricted Boltzmann Machine. The set-up is described as follows:

[...] Gauss-Bernoulli RBM, defined by: $$p(x) \propto \sum_h \exp(x^TBh + c_1^Tx + x_2^Th - \frac{1}{2}\lVert x\rVert^2_2)$$
where $x \in R^d$ and $h \in \{±1\}^{d′}$ is a binary latent variable. By marginalizing the hidden variable $h$, we can see that $p(x)$ is a special GMM with $2^{d′}$ components.
In our experiments, we draw the parameters $c_1$ and $c_2$ from standard Gaussian and select each element of B randomly from {±0.5} with equal probabilities. We set the dimension $d$ of $x$ to be 20 and the dimension $d′$ of $h$ to be 10 so that $p(x)$ is a 20-dimensional GMM with $2^{10}$ components, for which it is still feasible to draw exact samples by brute-force for the purpose of evaluation.

Now, I do not quite understand how this density, or energy, can be used to sample exactly, which I understand as not using MCMC, but I also have to admit that I am not very familiar with RBMs. In an implementation, I it is obviously relatively straightforward to code up the specified density and to sample $B, c_1, c_2$. But how can I sample from $p(x)$ exactly?
